# Same memory location assignment for two static variables

Tags: c, arrays, static, memory-address

I have the below code and I see that the two variables have been assigned with same address. Both the variables are completely different type . Is there anyway I can void this ? And under what circumstances does the same memory gets allocated to both the variables .

```
static int Sw_Type [];
static BOOL Sw_Update;

void main()
{
  int i;
  int bytes = 3;
  if (Sw_Update!= TRUE)
  {
    for(i = 0; i< bytes ;i++)
    {
      Sw_Type [i] = *Ver_Value;     
      Ver_Value++;          
    }
    Sw_Update= TRUE;
  }
}
```

This is a snippet of my code and "Ver_Value" is a structure which gets assigned in different function.

So the problem I am seeing is , when Sw_Update gets updated, Sw_Type [1] is getting updated and I see these two have same memory address.

Comment: how much memory do you think gets allocated with: `static int Sw_Type [];`?

Comment: Empty arrays are illegal in C.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: There is no empty array in the code shown. There is an array of incomplete type. (It could have been completed.)

Comment: The limit on your `for` loop is `3`. Therefore, it is using array index values in the range 0-2. But, your array only defines a single element. You want: `static int Sw_Type [3];` But, if you increase `bytes`, you'll need to adjust the array accordingly. This is not a great way to do this. (e.g.) You'd be better off with `#define bytes 3` above the array and then: `static int Sw_Type [bytes];`

Comment: @chux: Clang is okay with completing it later. I am not sure whether 6.9.2 3 is intended to be applied to each declaration as it appears or to the resolved composite type at the end of the translation unit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As I see it, `static int Sw_Type [];` is a  _tentative definition_ yet  `static int Sw_Type [];` is certainly an _incomplete type_.  And that makes it invalid C here with `static`.  It is one of those LL rabbit holes that get into the corners of C, yet could be avoided with `static int Sw_Type [SOME_CONSTANT];`  I get `error: array size missing in 'Sw_Type'
   static int Sw_Type [];` with gcc -std=c11

Comment: @chux: Yes, `static int Sw_Type[];` is a tentative definition, and the type is incomplete, but that is not in dispute. Per 6.9.2 2, the behavior is **exactly as if** the translation unit contained `static int Sw_Type[] = { 0 };`, which is not a declaration with an incomplete type. [GCC does not give me that error unless I add `-pedantic`](https://godbolt.org/z/_kD0bN), so maybe the GCC developers had some question about the interpretation too.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Fair enough - notice the "... with an initializer equal to 0." part with `§6.9.2 2` could be interpreted as attempting `static int Sw_Type[] = 0;` and initializing an array with 0 is a no-no.  Interesting the corners of C.

Comment: @chux: Yes, I thought that about the initializer too. But Example 2 tells us to effectively use `= { 0 }` for aggregates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static int Sw_Type [];` constitutes a *tentative definition*, per C 2018 6.9.2 2:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier **static**, constitutes a *tentative definition*. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

Since your program provides no non-tentative definition, it is as if it ended with `static int Sw_Type [] = { 0 };`. (In case it is not clear from the text quoted above that the result is indeed an array of one element, it is made clear by Example 2 in paragraph 5 of the same clause.)

Thus, `Sw_Type` is an array of one `int`. It contains only the element `Sw_Type[0]`. The behavior of accessing `Sw_Type[1]` is not defined by the C standard. From the observations you report, it appears as if `Sw_Update` follows `Sw_Type` in memory, and accessing `Sw_Type[1]` results in modifying `Sw_Update`. This behavior is of course not reliable.

To make `Sw_Type` larger, you must declare a size for it, as with `static int Sw_Type[4];`.

Note: 6.9.2 3 says “If the declaration of an identifier for an object is a tentative definition and has internal linkage, the declared type shall not be an incomplete type.” While this might be read as applying to the declared type in each declaration that is a tentative definition, I think it might be intended to apply to the declared type of the object once its composite type is fully resolved at the end of the translation unit. Experimentally, Clang is okay with accepting an incomplete type at first and completing it later.

Comment: Thank you Eric! Declaring a size solved my problem . I have a question on dynamic size .  When the size is dynamic which is the best data structure to be used?

Comment: @pranathi: For dynamic sizes, you do not define an array. You define a pointer to the desired type. Then, when the program is running, you call `malloc` to allocate space for as many objects as desired, and you set the pointer to point to that space.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am doing Embedded programming , I cannot use malloc since it would cost me time and freeing is not hassle free. Is there any other way I can do this ? Thanks!

Comment: @pranathi: You either reserve memory at compile time, which requires a size at compile time, or you reserve memory at execution time, which requires some means of allocating memory at execution time. If you have a maximum amount of memory that may be required, you can reserve all of that at compile time, even if less is used at execution time. Otherwise, you must provide memory at execution time. Perhaps it might come from the stack in your system, but, one way or another, you must provide memory.

Comment: Thank you ! That helps!

Answer (score 1):

> So the problem I am seeing is , when Sw_Update gets updated, Sw_Type [1] is getting updated and I see these two have same memory address.

There is no `Sw_Type [1]`. Only an array with two or more elements has a second entry, and `Sw_Type` is not an array with two or more elements. Accessing an array out of bounds can certainly stomp on other objects.